# -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch kills overflow: hidden

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, webkit

I'm working on a webapp to order some images ([Website](http://m.zardo.ch)).

Now, on my iphone it didn't scroll smooth, so i added `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`. But now i can scroll vertically see [here](http://m.zardo.ch/bild-bearbeiten/?mediaId=1908&mediaType=Umbraco).

I already tried to add `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` to other elements, but without success.
Also no success with change the `overflow`.

This problem is only reproducible on the iphone.

If someone has an idea how to fix this issue i would be so glad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just added a new container. This fixed my issue for the IPhone.

```
* {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 37px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```